# Type definition for functions in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In a recent coding situation, I found out that (A)`onPress?(): void` is a valid alternative for (B) `onPress?: () => void`. I do prefer B over A, because it looks like it's more common in the TypeScript community and because of the consistency of defining your prop name, `?` if necessary for optional props, separated by a `:` and then your type.

My question is: is there any documentation why A is also correct, or in which way it's different from B? Or is it just the same? Or is one of both more preferred?

Thanks in advance!

```
type Props = {
   onPress?(): void
}

type OtherProps = {
   onPress?: () => void
}

const instanceOfProps: Props = {
    onPress: () => {}
}

const instanceOfOtherProps: OtherProps = {
    onPress: () => {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A is just syntax sugar for B in this case. I believe it's based on [ES6 object initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015), which support using `onPress() {...}` for a function value. However since you're creating a type, TypeScript is only concerned with types and not implementations, so `{...}` is replaced with `: type`.

Personally I prefer A, as it's shorter, more consistent with ES6, and looks more like a property type in TypeScript.